# Datatable group by having c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Datatable called "`ConflictData`".
I want to do this SQL command by using `LINQ`

```
Select ID from ConflictData group by ID,DesignArticle,DesignNo,PatternCode having count(ID)>=2))
```

I try this

```
   var ID = from item in ConflictDatas.AsEnumerable()
                             group item by new
                 {
                     ID = item.ID,
                     DesignArticle = item.DesignArticle,
                     DesignNo = item.DesignNo,
                     PatternCode = item.PatternCode
                 } into g
                             where g.Count() > 2
                             select new
                              {
                                  ID = g.Key.ID
                              };
```

But it show the error:

> Error  2   'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ID','DesignArticle','DesignNo','PatternCode' and no extension method 'ID','DesignArticle','DesignNo','PatternCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I pretty sure datatable "`ConflictDatas`" have these Columns.

How do I modify my `LINQ` ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you included `using System.Data`?

Comment: are you querying against a `DataTable` in memory?

Comment: I already included using System.Data

Comment: are you querying against a DataTable in memory --> Yes

Comment: If you have a DataRow then use item.Field<string>("ID")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Field<datatype>("columnName")` to fetch cell value of given column in datatable row as below

```
var ID = from item in ConflictDatas.AsEnumerable()
                             group item by new
                 {
                     ID = item.Field<int>("ID"),
                     DesignArticle = item.Field<string>("DesignArticle"),
                     DesignNo = item.Field<string>("DesignNo"),
                     PatternCode = item.Field<string>("PatternCode")
                 } into g
                             where g.Count() > 2
                             select new
                              {
                                  ID = g.Key.ID
                              };
```